# How to handle login window in selenium for https://www.flipkart.com/

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

When open `https://www.flipkart.com/` a window opens for login. How to handle this window in selenium?

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "F:\\Software_Sel\\GekoDriver\\geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();
wd.get("https://www.flipkart.com/")                     
WebElement e1= wd.findElement(By.className("_2AkmmA _29YdH8")); 
e1.click();
```

I have also tried iframe. But cant handle.Kindly help.

Comment: It's just a modal window which you can handle in the same way as any other element

Answer (score 0):

The class name you are using _2AkmmA _29YdH8 contains two class. ClassName locators only work for single class name .Instead of that you should use css ._2AkmmA._29YdH8

```
WebElement e1=
```

wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("._2AkmmA._29YdH8"))

Hope this helps u

Answer (score 0):

The login window and the elements within are part of the same [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) so you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class Login_Window_Flipkart {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\\\geckodriver.exe");
          WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();
          wd.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");                    
          new WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Enter Email/Mobile number')]//preceding::input[1]"))).sendKeys("Abhijit@Datta.com");
          wd.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Enter Password')]//preceding::input[1]")).sendKeys("Abhijit@Datta.com");
      }
  }
  ```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: flipkart_login_window]

Comment: @AbhijitDatta Please accept the Answer by clicking on the hollow check mark beside my Answer which is just below the votedown arrow so the check mark turns green.